# How to use OpenCV to read a traditional thermometer

Tags: opencv

I'm new to OpenCV looking for direction on best approach to reading a traditional thermometer using computer vision. Any guidance, general approach, sample code? Thanks for any consideration on this very broad question.

So I guess more specifically how do you narrow your contours to your area of interest, such as just having bounding boxes around just the numbers for instance in the the attached image. Thanks for any consideration. [1]: http://eofdreams.com/photo/thermometer/05/ "thermometer"

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('thermometer.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
keys = [i for i in range(48,58)]
#cnts = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]
for cnt in contours:
    #if cv2.contourArea(cnt)>50:
    [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
    roi = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    roismall = cv2.resize(roi,(10,10))
    cv2.imshow('norm',img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite('houghlines3.jpg',edges)
```

Comment: [tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/)

Comment: You had better narrow this down or it will surely get closed for being too broad. An image of the thermometer that you want to read would help, and some ideas that you have tried and why they don't work.

Comment: how much manual work is ok? if the view is static, the user might for example mark the upper and lower bound of the thermometer and set temperature values to those borders? In that case, the task of reading a thermometer is reduced to reading the position of the "red line", which might be done by HSV color classification.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that is pretty general.  I don't know what computer vision is, but I'm guessing it's some software that looks at said thermometer.

So first of all think in terms of what this software can understand.  I'm going to guess that it can pick up on a color change.  So you should be able to know when the colors go from red to white (or whatever it is when the thermometer is not red).   The program may or may not be smart enough to read the numbers indicating the temperature along the thermometer (I'm assuming this is a vertical thermometer).  If the #s are written on glass or a curved, the software probably won't be able to read it.  However if it is black letters on a flat white background you may be in luck. Can you then find the closest # to where the red transitions to white?  If not you may need to calibrate ahead of time the temperature that is associated with varying heights.  In that case you will essentially be ignoring the written #s and be hardcoding them into your program.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its a static image you can calculate a scale of x pixels = y degrees. Or, well approximately... You can detect the high point of the mercury with simple colour detection, convert image to hsv, filter out with in range to leave just the red, then find the smallest y val and check against your scale.

Finding the Assuming a constant linear scale and each x amount of pixels in the y-axis is equal to y degrees will be easier than trying to detect the digits and read them. Though, to answer your question, as your digits are constant, I'd recommend cropping around the known positions of the numbers and template matching, but that's still pointless as the numbers won't change, so you can just hardcode the positions!

or, if it's a real world scenario, either use a digital thermometer and detect the lcd digits with template matching, or connect a thermometer to the computer.